# Matplotlib - Whitespace in Variable used for Filename

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I am creating several plots using a dataframe. The code looks somewhat like this:

```
for x in df.col1.unique():
    temp = df_institution.col2.value_counts()
    result = pd.DataFrame(temp)

    plt.bar(result['role'], result['number of nodes'])
    plt.savefig('.plots/political_analysis/institution/' + str(x) + '.png')
    plt.close()
```

The issue lies in the line where I want to save the plots. Many of the x values have white spaces, for instance 'apple pie'. Of course, when running the code this raises errors. What would be a clever way to bypass this, so I do not have to save each plot individually?

Comment: Simply `for x in df.col1.str.replace(' ','_').unique()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly, the problem is the space " " you have in the variable `x`?
If that is the problem, you can simply replace the occurrence of such spaces in `x`'s.

```py
str(x).replace(' ', '_')
```

Comment: @luthienaerendell this is generally called string manipulation in programming, check more operations online (one such website that can be useful is https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_ref_string.asp)